# На чем был создан Telegram?

Tags: mobile-development

У меня конкретный вопрос, какие Developer tools использовал Дуров, чтобы сделать Telegram?

Вовремя использования приложения я заметил что приложение просто летает. И я у меня появился вопрос, если приложение вышло одновременно на iOS и Android значит он мог использывать какие-то кроссплотформенные Dev Tools. Но разве возможно добится такой оптимизации приложения не используя нативные?

Comment: у Вас ложная предпосылка - то, что они вышли одновременно, не значит, что их нельзя разрабатывать одновременно.

Comment: А они нативные. Смотрите версию [под Android](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram), [под iOS](https://github.com/peter-iakovlev/Telegram).

Answer (score 1):

Исходный код для компьютеров доступен на GitHub

https://github.com/telegramdesktop

Comment: Можно подробнее про исзодный код. Я видел там 5 Builds. Это IDE которые использовались при создании, я прав?

Comment: Немного ошибся, это для компьютеров доступен на гитхабе,  5 IDE на которых можно собрать свою программу.